# IPX Networking with DOS and DOSBox (under Raspbian)

Tags: go, networking, raspbian, dosbox

My long-term-goal is to get Doom (version 1.1) running in [3 screen mode](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=58114#p643845) on a mix of hardware (1 x Pentium 3 under DOS 7.10 and 2 x Raspberry Pis under Raspbian).

I have DOS running LNE100TX (I can share the configuration files if that is helpful).

I enabled IPX in the configuration file started DOSBox under Raspbian.

```
[ipx]
# ipx: Enable ipx over UDP/IP emulation.
ipx=true

pi@raspberrypi:~$ dosbox
DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file /home/pi/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf
MIXER:No Sound Mode Selected.
ALSA:Can’t subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
```

I started the ipx server and mounted the drive in DOSBox

```
Z:\>ipxnet startserver 19900
IPX Tunneling utility for DosBox
IPX Tunneling Server started

Z:\>mount c ~/dos-games
Drive C is mounted as local directory /home/pi/dos-games/
```

I found [ipxbox](https://github.com/fragglet/ipxbox) on Github which says:

> ipxbox is a standalone DOSBox IPX server written in Go. DOSBox clients can connect to the server and play together.
>
> A unique feature is that it is optionally able to bridge to real
>   physical networks, in a manner similar to a VPN. DOSBox clients can
>   communicate with each other on the server, but with this feature
>   enabled they can also communicate with physical IPX nodes on the
>   connected network. So emulated DOS clients should be able to play
>   games against real DOS machines connected to the same network.

So, I installed Go:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export GOPATH=/home/pi/work
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install golang
```

Then I attempted to install ipxbox:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ go get github.com/fragglet/ipxbox
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd work
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ go build ipxbox.go
```

This is the message that I get when I run this command:

```
#github.com/google/gopacket/pcap
go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap_unix.go:34:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
#include <pcap.h>
compilation terminated.
```

Perhaps this is obvious, but I'm not very familiar with Linux.  Does anyone have any suggestions for what is causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what I got a down vote.  I tried to be clear on what steps I took and researched solutions before I posted this question.  Perhaps, to some, the solution was obvious.  But it wasn't to me.  Anyhow, thanks to eandersson for the quick (and correct) response.

Comment: Chiefly because your question is not really about _using_ Go (I did not down vote, FWIW.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the pcap development packages.

> sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev